# textarea and selector option not being sent to email

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, textarea

I have searched as suggested but have not found why my version of the form does not work. I have a form that collects name, email, phone, a select option and a message in a textarea input. I change the textarea and action php based off the user option selected in the select input.

I use PHP to email the form contentse. I get ALL fields except for:
-Message/Comments

**HTML**

```
<!-- Career Form -->
<form id="careerContactForm" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- $name -->
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 required">
      <label for="contact-name">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- $email -->
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 required">
      <label for="contact-email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <!-- $phone -->
    <div class="col-md-4 required">
      <label for="contact-phone">Phone Number</label><br />
      <input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-country="US" id="contact-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- $who -->
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 required select-wrapper">
    <!-- Contact -->
      <label for="contact-who">Who are you trying to contact?</label>
      <select class="selectorWho form-control" name="who" required>
        <option value="None"><em>--Please Select One--</em></option>
        <option value="general">General</option>
        <option value="HR / Careers">HR / Careers</option>
        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="td">TDXperts</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- $interest -->
  <div class="row form-group hidden uploadResume">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 required select-wrapper">
     <!-- Career -->
      <label>I'm looking for employment opportunities in…</label>
      <select class="selector-career form-control" name="interest" required>
        <option value="None"><em>--Please Select One--</em></option>
        <option value="Accounting">Accounting</option>
        <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
        <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="general">General</option>
        <option value="HR">HR</option>
        <option value="IT">IT</option>
        <option value="Logistics & Customs Affairs">Logistics & Customs Affairs</option>
        <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
        <option value="Purchasing">Purchasing</option>
        <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="Supply Chain Planning">Supply Chain Planning</option>
        <option value="Warehouse">Warehouse</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 required">
      <label for="uploadResume">Upload Your Resume</label>
      <input type="file" name="resume" id="resume-upload">
      <p class="help-block"><em>You must choose a valid file. We accept .doc, .docx, .pdf, .rtf and .txt files</em></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Career Submit: hide / show -->
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 hidden careerContact">
      <!-- Contact -->
      <label for="contact-message">Questions or Comments</label>
      <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="6" id="contact-message" class="form-control" placeholder="Would you like to include any more information?" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 hidden contactMessage">
      <!-- Career -->
      <label for="career-message">Message</label>
      <textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="6" id="career-message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message..." ></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Send message</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS (that show/hide textareas and show/hide file upload dialog)**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".selectorWho").on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var uploadResume = $('.uploadResume');
    var comments = $('.contactMessage');
    var careerComments = $('.careerContact');
    if (this.value == "HR / Careers") {
        uploadResume.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");
        careerComments.removeClass("hidden");
        comments.addClass("hidden");
        var action = "do/careers-submit.php";
        var submitButton = 'career-submit';
    } else {
        uploadResume.slideUp().addClass('hidden');
        careerComments.addClass('hidden');
        comments.removeClass("hidden");
        var action = "do/contact-submit.php";
        var submitButton = 'contact-submit';
    }
    $("#careerContactForm").attr("action", action);
});
});
```

**PHP (for one of the actions)**

```
<?php 
    require("../classes/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $who = $_POST['who'];
    $interest = $_POST['interest'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->From     = "$email";
    $mail->FromName = "$name";
    // $mail->AddAddress("hr@tireco.com","Tireco HR");
    $mail->AddAddress("vs@tireco.com","Tireco HR");
    $mail->Subject  = "New Resume Submission";
    $mail->Body     = "Name:\n $name\n\n\nPhone:\n $phone\n\n\nEmail:\n $email\n\n\nContacting:\n $who\n\n\nInterested In:\n -$interest\n\n\nQuestions/Comments:\n $comments";

    if (isset($_FILES['resume']) &&
        $_FILES['resume']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['resume']['name']);
    }

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo 'Message was not sent.';
      echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        header( 'Location: ../thankYou.html' ) ;
    }
?>
```

So, I get all fields **except** for the message/comments textarea text.

If you would like to see what I get in the email [click here](http://i1068.photobucket.com/albums/u450/vs-works/Capture_zpseogyikvr.jpg)

If you clicked, you saw what I get when I submit a *HR/Careers > IT + Upload File + Message*...The message is omitted.

Thank you in advance for your help.

VS

Comment: What is this code NOT doing that you need it to do? What kind of output are you getting vs. what you expect? Do you have PHP errors turned on?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need the form to email me name, email, phone, "interest" (select option) and a coimments/message. I am receiving a mail with only the name, email and phone. I need to receive he textarea with comments and the option they selected in the select input. How do I turn PHP errors "on?"

Comment: Go to your php.ini file in your PHP directory. About 250 to 400 lines down you will find a section labeled 'Error handling and logging'. Go down to the 'Common Values' option and uncomment "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT' and remove any following text. This will show all errors, except for notices. You will have to re-boot for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your select box a name, not the option.

You have

```
<select id="interest" class="selector-career form-control" required>
```

It needs to be

```
<select name="interest" id="interest" class="selector-career form-control" required>
```

With regards to the file attachment you should probably check the file uploaded ok

```
if (isset($_FILES['resume']) &&
    $_FILES['resume']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['resume']['name']);
}
```

Comment: _$message = $_POST['message'];_ is in the other action php file I have. I switch action files based off of the first select box selection.

Eventhough I have the "comments" code it comes through the email as "blank"

Comment: @vs-works ah ok, So the bit I wrote about the select box should fix one of the things. With regards to attachments you should probably check if the file upload was ok. I will update my answer with some more code

Comment: Thank you for that code. But what about me not receiving textarea messages? That is the part that is baffling me.

Comment: where is the end form tag </form> for the form? Can you update your question with the changes i've mentioned and let me know

Comment: @vs-works forgot to mention you in my above comment. Also if you aren't closing the form in the correct place there may be another element on your page with the name="comments" and it's using that instead. If there another form anywhere else on the page?

Comment: I edited my OP. I simplified the form so you should be able to see the closing form tag and I added your correction to the PHP. I also cleaned up the JS a bit. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: All that remains now is to have the message be delivered in the email. Everything else works!

Comment: Can i get any help on the textarea not being passed in?

Comment: @vs-works can you do a print_r($_POST);die; and tell me if the $_POST['comments'] has a value

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for my selectors, which I have inside a div / form wrapper.
 *You need to select an index of the option, not the option container*.
 This is for selecting States, of which I have removed most to save space. Look at it's structure and modify your code.
 Notice the square brackets that index the option your client selected. "state_sel" is the variable that contains the selected item. I left out my button for a function call.

```
 <form id="state_opt" name="state_opt">&nbsp;State
<select id="state_mgr" onChange="state_sel=document.state_opt.state_mgr.options[document.state_opt.state_mgr.selectedIndex].value;">
<option selected value="0">None</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama
<option value="MT">Montana
<option value="WI">Wisconsin
<option value="MO">Missouri
<option value="WY">Wyoming
</select>
```

Comment: Thank for your input. I achieved what I needed with the selector using the "name" attribute. That is all I needed to specify to be able to pass the value that the user selects and send it through email via my PHP..